# Water pressure an salinity sensor connected to arduino

Tags: electrical-engineering, design

I am trying to design a project that Arduino would have connected water and salinity sensor, would be packed in a special box be dropped into ocean up to 500 meters. What sensors should I use and how should they be connected? I assume that I would need professional equipment, not Chinese stuff from eBay.
Hardware needs to be able to work under 50°C and up to 50 bar.

- Budget is about up to 400 pounds for sensors.
- Resolution of pressure sensor 0 to 100 bar.
- Resolution of salinity sensor doesn't matter so much. Few percent's tolerance, just to measure it somehow.

Comment: Hi Mateusz, welcome to Engineering SE. Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with [what type of question we accept](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In particular, we don't do shopping questions like this, for the reasons described [here](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/368). Once you have selected parts for your device, we might be able to help with any specific problems you encounter with the design or function of the device itself.